# android relative layout contains image view layout

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a image view inside of a relative view, as per code below

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/maintenance_banner"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

what i don't understand is the gaps at the top & bottom, as I have set both height to wrap_content, the gaps shouldn't be part of the content, only the imageview it self isn't it? Or does it means the gaps are part of the image view it self? but i set the padding to 0. also, for some reason I can get ride of them by setting scale type.

[image: layout screen shot]

Comment: First if you want it on top then why android:layout_alignParentTop="false"?
Also are you sure there isn't any transparency in the image you're using?

Comment: the image doesn't contain any transparency, and the align top line is somehow generated by the ide

Answer (score 0):

The image probably has another aspect ratio then your imageView.

Try to set the `android:scaleType` to centerCrop or whatever else does work for you.

The default scale type is: [FIT_CENTER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) and FIT_XY for buttons.

Hope this helps

EDIT: Sorry I haven't seen the wrap content. 
From the screenshot it looks like you have other views below, are you including this layout file into another one?

Cheers

Comment: image view size should adjust along with the size of the actual image as the height is set to be wrap_content, isn't it?